# What is a propellant burner trailer?

Tags: launch, fuel, identify-this-object, launch-site, launchpad

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/08/30/politics/trump-tweet-iran-missile/index.html) and [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2019/08/30/755994591/president-trump-tweets-sensitive-surveillance-image-of-iran) have pointed out that the US president [recently tweeted](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1167493371973255170/photo/1) a surveillance photo of an explosion of a rocket on a launch pad.

One of the items identified in the photo is labeled as a `propellant burner trailer`.

**Question:** What is a propellant burner, and why would it be in a trailer?

[image]

---

Comment: related, in Aviation SE: [What kind of drone might be able to fly so high that it “operate(s) outside national boundaries”?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/68289/14213)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is largely speculative but based upon knowledge of similar systems.

1. The Safir space launch vehicle may use hypergolic [propellants](https://www.spacelaunchreport.com/safir.html).
2. The launch site shown in the photograph has minimal permanent
   infrastructure.
3. Hypergolic propellant storage facilities at Johnson Space Center and
   White Sands Test Facility have burner stacks to safely dispose of vented propellants. ([KSC-2010-045R](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100042352.pdf), pages 53 and 44).

Speculative conclusion: the trailer is (was) a portable means of storing the vehicle's propellants and is (was) equipped with burner stacks to safely dispose of vented propellant.

(Crop of largest version of picture I could find, showing possible tanks in the trailer. from ["The Drive"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZ6vW89qvkAhXJ6Z4KHTPtAOAQjhx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thedrive.com%2Fthe-war-zone%2F29634%2Ftrump-tweets-intelligence-image-after-irans-rocket-explosion-and-offers-them-best-wishes&psig=AOvVaw0tPeXQ8iGtSguDki2H3aiw&ust=1567300087881504))

[image]

Comment: Some sources say the propellant is UDMH with IRFNA, which are probably a little less nasty when combined and burned than they are separately.

Comment: @RussellBorogove thanks, I will soften up point 1.

Comment: Soften? The article you linked suggested (either UDMH or hydrocarbon) + unnamed storable oxidizer; I was just passing along that other sources suggest that IRFNA is the oxidizer and support the UDMH end of the speculation.

Comment: Are IRFNA and UDMH hypergolic? I don't know, so was trying to avoid claiming that they are.

Comment: Oh yeah they are.

Comment: Looks like they are according to wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergolic_propellant#Hypergolic_combinations I'll put it back.  Thanks again.